# Avoiding branching using arrays

Tags: c++, branch

let's say I have an very simple function called `foo`. Foo can return two values, I'll use `x` and `y` as arbitrary placeholder variables.

I define it like so:

```cpp
int foo(bool expression)
{
    static const int x = ..., y = ...;

    if(expression)
        return x;
    else
        return y;
}
```

This **obviously** a branching statement

I was thinking doing something like the following could remove any branching:

```cpp
int foo(bool expression)
{
    static const int array[] = {x, y};

    return array[expression];
}
```

Yet I'm not sure if, by using C arrays, it still incurs branching, does it? Do C++ `std::` arrays or vectors cause branching?

Is it worth it to attempt to read from the array, or is it a waste of memory and execution speed?

And lastly, if the `expression` contained a logical expression, such as `&&`, does this mean it will still branch?

Comment: The argument is not a expression, it is a value and is either `true` or `false`.

Comment: "*This is obviously a branching statement*" Not so obvious to me. Compilers are good at optimizing code, it could do the same optimization as you did in second snippet (if it's really helping). Did you profile your code and found this particular function to be a bottleneck? If not, **don't optimize it**.

Comment: Why would indexing into an array cause any branching?

Comment: @molbdnilo That's why I'm asking, I don't know what the compiler does. I assumed it didn't, but is it a waste to read from the array?

Comment: You should check https://godbolt.org/z/fbjFno

Comment: @ThomasSablik I planned on checking out a similar web site if SO didn't give me any good anwers.

Comment: That's the wrong order. First check yourself. Then ask.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Okay, but I was asking this for a general view. Would the same thing happen in Python? Would this branch in Java? What about JS?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A platform. You ask **one** question and get answers. Currently there are 4 different questions.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Well, at least two of the questions are more of sub questions. But I guess I ought to separate this into 4 different posts...

Comment: @ThomasSablik: And with optimization turn on, none versions use branching :) [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/CJRrBe)

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm pretty sure that is incorrect.

Comment: @JadenGarcia: Branching are conditional jump asm instructions (such as `je`/`jne`). And there is a conditional jump instruction only in non-optimized first snippet.

Comment: @Jarod42 That is only because the values can be computed at compile time, as if they were implicitly `constexpr`.

Comment: @JadenGarcia: even with external `x`/`y` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TSfEwX). conditional jump is only to handle static initialization.

Comment: @Jarod42 Helpful to note, leave it to the compiler on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as `condition` relies on a boolean value to know what to do next, then it's definitely branching. It's reasonable to say that the code itself needs to wait and branch to decide which element from the array to access and return.

By the same concept, `&&` or any other logical operator implies branching.

Comment: As we can see from [godbold link](https://godbolt.org/z/fbjFno) provided by Thomas Sablik, there are no conditional jumps in second version. With [optimization](https://godbolt.org/z/CJRrBe) turned on, none versions uses jump.

Answer (score 0):

The question is complicated by the fact that in one case you are showing a `bool` `expression`, in the other case you are showing an `int` `condition`.

If your expression naturally evaluates to an `int`, then using this `int` to pick up an item from the array will not involve any branching.  If the most natural type that your expression evaluates to is `bool`, then you will need to convert it to an `int`, and this conversion is likely to internally involve branching, so you are probably not going to gain anything.  I am saying "probably" because a lot depends on the compiler and on the underlying CPU instruction set, so you will not know unless you have your compiler produce disassembly and examine the disassembly.

That having been said, I would add that your quest to eliminate a branch is rather an exercise in futility.  There is nothing inherently evil with branching, nor does it perform badly. True, it is best to eliminate branches, but only if it is trivial to do so.  If, in order to eliminate branching, you introduce an array that you otherwise wouldn't have, then you are probably adding an order of magnitude more overhead than you are saving.  If you introduce a vector instead of an array, you may be introducing twice the overhead of the array.  So, my recommendation about this would be: do not worry about the branching.

Comment: Sorry! Error on my part, fixing immediately.

Comment: Might I ask, even when I had accidentally written "condition," I never defined it as an `int`, what brought you to assume its data-type?

Comment: I assumed that because generally, arrays are indexable by `int`.

Comment: Oh, that would've gone well out of bounds, I made this array with a size of 2, allowing it to be indexed by a boolean value instead. But thank you for your answer, it helped me make my decision.